# How to solve the equation for $x$ with integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone explain to me how to solve this integration?

$$a-b\int_{0}^{x}[1-F(z)]dz+x=0$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $F(z)$ is a cumulative distribution function (the distribution is not specified), how can I solve for $x$ from this equation?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to solve for $x$?

Comment: I am not sure, i just hope to use the inverse function $F^{-1}$ to express the x. or something else.

Comment: what is the domain of definition of F(x)? Even that probably won't save the equation though, since it implies that F(x) is a constant .

Comment: $z$ should be a non-negative value and $F(z)$ should be between 0 to 1 because $F(z)$ is a Cumulative distribution function. $x$ also should be non-negative value.

Comment: Then there is no solution to what you're asking for. Just take a derivative wrt to x and convince yourself.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained where this equation came from.

Comment: If you take the derivative, you get $b(1-F(x))=1$  Does this help?

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it

Answer (score 2):

Let $~b\neq 0~$

$$a-b\int_{0}^{x}[1-F(z)]dz+x=0$$

Differentiating with respect to $~x~$ using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we have

$$-~b~\frac{d}{dx}~\int_{0}^{x}[1-F(z)]dz~+~1~=0$$
$$\implies -~b~[1-F(x)]+1=0$$
$$\implies F(x)=\frac{b-1}{b}\qquad \text{as $~b\neq 0~$}$$
$$\implies x=F^{-1}\left(\frac{b-1}{b}\right)$$

---

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Does the diffrential solution is the same with original one? like $x^2+2x=0$ solution x=0 or -2, but after dififferentiation, we get $2x+2=0$ x=-1, this two solutions are different.

Comment: Look, if $~f(x)=x^2+2x=0~$, then $~g(x)=\frac{df}{dx}=2x+2=0~$. Here both $~f(x)~$ and $~g(x)~$ are totally different function. The only relation between them is $~g(x)=\frac{df}{dx}~$. So it is quite natural that there roots are also different.

Comment: So your solution $x=F^{-1}(\frac{b-1}{b})$ is only for the equation after differentiation, not satisfy the original one, is that right?

Comment: By the way, you can't edit like this, when the answer of a question is given already (3 days ago). If you have any doubt you can ask in the comment portion, or ask a new question tagging this one.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you familiar about Rolle's theorem ? @Aeeh

Comment: Rolle's theorem: If a function $~f~$ defined on $~[a,~b]~$ is $~~(1)~~$ continuous on  $~[a,~b]~$, $~~(2)~~$ derivable on $~(a,~b)~$, and $~~(3)~~$ $~f(a)=f(b)~$, then there exists at least one real number $~c~$ between $~a,~$and $~b~$ $~(a\lt c\lt b)~$such that $~f'(c)=0~$

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Comment: I think you got your answer

Comment: See the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250863/solution-of-fredholm-integral-equation/3250970#3250970

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

The given integral equation is $$a-b\int_{0}^{x} |1-f(z)|dz+x=0.$$ Differentiate w.r.t. $x$, then
$$-b |1-f(x)|+1=0 \Rightarrow |1-f(x)|=\frac{1}{b}\Rightarrow f(x)=1+\frac{1}{b},~\mbox{or}~ f(x)=1-\frac{1}{b} ~\mbox{b}>0.$$ No solution if $b<0.$

Comment: I think you meant $1-\frac1b$ at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it.

Comment: Please see the edited version.